# Suggestion on handling realtime data in AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-iot, aws-appsync

I'm working on an application that provides a snapshot of the the data in realtime.
The data is currently stored in DynamoDB. The current state of the data should be displayed on a simple html page. 
One of the options I've explored so far is
DynamoDB - Lambda - APIGateway. Most challenging part is the data push when the (intended data in the)DynamoTable is updated

Not sure if appsync or IoT would be of any help.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB Streams could help you to achieve your goals.

One of the case how to use it is:

*A popular mobile app modifies data in a DynamoDB table, at the rate of thousands of updates per second. Another application captures and stores data about these updates, providing near real time usage metrics for the mobile app.*

Check out more in the next article - [Capturing Table Activity with DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)

**Update:** API Gateway wasn't designed to stream data to a client. You could emulate it by calling API Gateway each 5-10 second. But it doesn't look as the best solution for this.

I suggest investigating [Amazon Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/). It is possible to trigger Kinesis from Lambda and implement Kinesis Consumer for reading Kinesis stream. You could check more details in the next article - [Developing Amazon Kinesis Data Streams Consumers Using the Kinesis Client Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-kcl.html).

On the other hand, you could try to implement this functionality without Lambda. I haven't seen a good example for this but this article describes something similar - [Processing Amazon DynamoDB Streams Using the Amazon Kinesis Client Library](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/processing-amazon-dynamodb-streams-using-the-amazon-kinesis-client-library/).

Comment: Thank you @RredCat. I've enabled the streams on my Dynamo table.
Does that mean that if the data is displayed on a html page via API Gateway, The html page would automatically update with the change in data- How does the browser know about the change in the data.
Also  - API Gateway doesn't support websockets as of now. Kindly suggest.

Comment: You can use Ajax to call your API every interval, this API will check for the update in dynamodb and display new information if available

Answer (score 0):

You might find AppSync to be helpful for your use case. It has data sources you can configure, one type of which is Dynamo. Further, there is a concept of subscriptions, which sends updates to subscribed devices when the data they're subscribed to is updated, which sounds like what you are aiming for.

DynamoDB data sources: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html

Subscriptions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html